# Perfect Fowarding and the Use of std::forward<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I am currently trying to figure out how exactly perfect forwarding works. I have written a piece of example code that as far as I know performs perfect forwarding as it's supposed to be:

```
void whatIsIt(std::vector<int>&& variable)
{
  std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
}

void whatIsIt(std::vector<int>& variable)
{
  std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void performPerfectForwarding(T&& variable)
{
  whatIsIt(std::forward<T>(variable));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::vector<int> lvalue;
  performPerfectForwarding(lvalue);
  performPerfectForwarding(std::move(lvalue));

  return 0;
}
```

Calling the function `performPerfectForwarding` with an lvalue makes it call the corresponding overload of `whatIsIt` and the same applies for calling it with an rvalue. Consequently, the output generated by this code is:

```
lvalue
rvalue
```

However, I was asking myself what the following versions of the function `performPerfectForwarding` would do:

1.

```
template <class T>
void performPerfectForwarding(T& variable)
{
  whatIsIt(std::forward<T>(variable));
}
```

2.

```
template <class T>
void performPerfectForwarding(T variable)
{
  whatIsIt(std::forward<T>(variable));
}
```

They both output:

```
rvalue
rvalue
```

Now, my questions are: What would these two alternative versions do and would they make sense in any possible context? How do the reference collapsing rules apply in these cases compared to how they apply in the aforementioned "correct" version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template <class T>
void performPerfectForwarding(T& variable)
{
    whatIsIt(std::forward<T>(variable));
}
```

When `variable` is not a *forwarding-reference*, `T` is deduced as `T` even for *lvalues* *(in constrast to being deduced as `T&`)*. This therefore casts `variable` to an *rvalue reference*, because:

```
forward<T> -> T&&
forward<T&> -> T&
forward<T&&> -> T&&
```

---

```
template <class T>
void performPerfectForwarding(T variable)
{
    whatIsIt(std::forward<T>(variable));
}
```

Same considerations apply here. `T` can never be an *lvalue reference* here, so `forward` will always cast to *rvalue reference*.

---

> What would these two alternative versions do and would they make sense in any possible context?

I don't think so, because your `forward` is basically a `move`.

---

> How do the reference collapsing rules apply in these cases compared to how they apply in the aforementioned "correct" version?

The rules are applied as usual here. Remember:

```
&  &  -> &
&  && -> &
&& &  -> &
&& && -> &&
```

In both cases there's no way to have `variable` become a `&&`.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer. There is still one thing I am asking myself though. If I call my function `perfectForwarding(T&&)` with an lvalue, why is T deduced as being of a reference type (`T&`). The collapsing rules would just give me ` &&` (from the function signature), resulting in `&&` when collapsed. Or would it actually result in `& &&`? Sorry if I appear a bit confused about how references work in combination with templates. Just if I had a function `doSth(int& parameter)` then parameter would still be of type `int`, not of type `int&`.

Comment: Or in other words: If I had `performPerfectForwarding(T&)` and would call that with an lvalue, `T` would evaluate as `T` not as `T&` inside the function. So is this some crazy special rule that only applies to these "universal references" (`T&&`)?

Comment: *'So is this some crazy special rule that only applies to these "universal references"?'* - pretty much yes. See [cppreference/template argument deduction/deduction from a function call/4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call).

Comment: Ok, thank you, so that's clear now. Consequently, assuming I wanted to declare a variable of my type within my perfect forwarding function, I thus, instead of just writing `T localVariable;`, would have to write `std::remove_reference<T>::type localVariable;`, because otherwise I would be declaring an uninitialised reference in case an lvalue is passed to the function.

Comment: Or would it actually be more correct to use `std::decay` instead of `std::remove_reference` in that case?

Comment: @user1488118: not unless you need everything `decay` does